# 2 functions inside a case

Tags: php, sql, pdo

im trying to add 2 functions inside a case in php.

I have 2 tables

- Orcamento
- Trabalho

when i click a button one record goes from orcamento to trabalho, but the record still stays on orcamento, is there a way to delete it? i will paste my code down below

```
 case "aceitar_o": {

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO trabalho (user, NomeCliente, mail, Telefone, descricao, estado) VALUES (:user, :NomeCliente, :mail, :Telefone, :descricao, 'Aprovado')");
    $stmt->bindParam(':user', $user);
    $stmt->bindParam(':NomeCliente', $NomeCliente);
    $stmt->bindParam(':mail', $mail);
    $stmt->bindParam(':Telefone', $Telefone);
    $stmt->bindParam(':descricao', $descricao);
    $stmt->bindParam(':estado', $estado);

    break;

}
```

is it possible to add another funcions below the " break; " ?

Comment: I'd have to say yes. You can add another function. Think I am a little confused by the question. Have you tried something and had it not work as expected?

Comment: why do you want to add it _"below the break"_? It will not be executed there. Why not above the break? Or do you want a 'dafault' case (without a break before)?

Comment: after reading your question the forth time I have an Idea of what you might want: preparing a second statement ($stmt2, the 'delete') and execute both later. ?

Comment: exactly @jeff i want to delete it after adding it on the other table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't execute anything after the `break`.

> break ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or switch structure.

-http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

You could make 2 functions and have them inside the `case`.

```
case "aceitar_o": {
     $values = array('user' => $user, 'nome' => $NomeCliente, 'mail' => $mail, 'fone' => $Telefone, 'descri' => $descricao, 'estado' =>$estado);
     update($conn, $values);
     delete($conn, $values);
break;
....
function update($conn, $params) {
      $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO trabalho (user, NomeCliente, mail, Telefone, descricao, estado) VALUES (:user, :NomeCliente, :mail, :Telefone, :descricao, 'Aprovado')");
      $stmt->bindParam(':user', $params['user']);
      $stmt->bindParam(':NomeCliente', $params['nome']);
      $stmt->bindParam(':mail', $params['mail']);
      $stmt->bindParam(':Telefone', $params['fone']);
      $stmt->bindParam(':descricao', $params['descric']);
      $stmt->execute(); // or you could just pass the $values to the execute if you name the index the same as the placeholders
}
```

Additionally you have no named `estado` placeholder. In your current query it is a static value.